# Laravel 5.4 method FIND

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I notice some using this code:

```
$User = User::find($id);
```

But for me PhpStorm shows alert:

> Method 'find' not found in \App\User

If I write code like this:

```
$User = User::all()->find($id);
```

then no alerts..

Can someone explain differences or why PhpStorm alerts me?

Answer (score 1):

So looks like when installed barry laravel-ide-helper , something not installed correctly..

Fixed this problem.

Just copy RAW text from: https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822

And put inside: _ide_helper.php

Also edited file: composer.json

```
        "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
        "php artisan ide-helper:meta",
        "php artisan optimize"
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you write the code like this

> $User = User::query()->find($id);

rather than use

> $User = User::all()->find($id);

After laravel 5.1

They put the complex select function away from the **Model class** .

Official document: 
https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html